# importing @angular/code outside angular project folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

so I have my angular 2 folder project, outside it I have a service folder "auth.service.ts" that imports `Injectable` from `@angular/core`. But because the service is outside the angular project folder it gives me an error `Cannot find module '@angular/core'.` Any ideas how to solve that keeping in mind I want to keep the service file outside the main folder
?

Comment: What gives you the error?  tsc? An editor?

Comment: try to ut the full path from where you file is .. for example import {Injectable} from './node_modules/@angular/@angular/core'

Comment: You could also just bundle it into the project by adding it to whatever bundler tech you're using (assuming you want to build it into your dist bundle and minify/uglify it along with all the rest of it). In the CLI, you'd just add it to the scripts array in angular-cli.json, in webpack you'd configure the script loader in webpack.config.json and require the external file in your entry point (index.js or some such).

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi this worked: `./app-folder/node_modules/@angular/core`. Do you have an idea why do we use `@` when importing angular modules? Thank you

Comment: I post it ad an answer.. can you rate it if it helped you? It works lime this because the colsero insidie node_nodules has the @

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi sure.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi colsero? what is a colsero?

Comment: Sorry i use mobile and is difficult to write:-).. i mean the folder.. if you take a look inside node_modules folder you Will see the angular 2 folder is called @angular

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi thanks

Comment: You wellcome.. very happy to helped you!! And thnx for your rating!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to ut the full path from where you file is .. for example

`import {Injectable} from './node_modules/@angular/@angular/core`'